# How to make a4j:commandLink execute action and show modalpanel?

Tags: jsf, richfaces, jsf-1.2, jboss-4.2.x, richfaces-modal

Jsf 1.2, Richfaces 3.3.3,

I got the following code working to show a richfaces:modalpanel:

```html
<ui:repeat id="albums" var="listvalue" 
    value="#{MyBean.getImagelist()}">
    <a4j:commandLink id="link" reRender="panel">
        <h:graphicImage id="image" url="My_image.jpg"/>
        <rich:componentControl for="panel" attachTo="link" operation="show"
            event="onclick"/>
    </a4j:commandLink>
</ui:repeat>
```

It works and the modalpanel is shown, but what I couldn't manage to do is call a method that is on MyBean, how do I do that?

UPDATE 1

I forgot to mention that i need to pass a `<f:param>` on that action

UPDATE 2

As requested, here's the exact code i have:

```
<ui:repeat id="al11" var="albumslistvalue1" 
value="#{AlbumDetailBean.getAlbumImagesList()}">
  <a4j:commandLink id="link" action="#{AlbumDetailBean.mudaIdatual()}" 
    reRender="panel"
    oncomplete="javascript:Richfaces.showModalPanel('panel');" >
    <a4j:actionparam name="idfotoatual" value="#{albumslistvalue1.id}" />
    <h:graphicImage id="image" 
    url="#{albumslistvalue1.albumimagename}"/>
   </a4j:commandLink>
</ui:repeat>
```

Comment: Where do you plan to execute your managed bean method, from a commandLink/commandButton inside the modalPanel or in the commandLink generated by the `<ui:repeat>`?

Comment: from the `<a4j:commandLink id="link">` generated by the `<ui:repeat>`

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you want the action called onclicking the link. I so, try the following:

```html
<a4j:commandLink id="link" action="#{myBean.myAction}" reRender="panel"
    oncomplete="Richfaces.showModalPanel('panel');">
      <a4j:actionparam assignTo="#{yourParam}" value="#{yourParamValue}"/>
    <h:graphicImage id="image" url="My_image.jpg"/>
</a4j:commandLink>
```

UPDATE: added param as requested.

Comment: I thought it would work, but the panel doesn't appear and the action isn't called either, also, I edited the question

Comment: I've updated the answer. It;s strange that is not working. Do you get any exception? Can you show your exact code?

Comment: Still not working, it must be a silly mistake, updating the question with the actual code

Comment: Possible problem? url="{# ...} instead of #{...}/ You also need the assignTo attribute like this: assignTo="#{yourBean.someProperty}"

Comment: the url was mistyped, on the code it's right, added assignTo, didn't work.
I'm debugging and I can see that the action isn't called at all